# How to interpret sudden jumps of improvement in training error vs. iteration?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, convolutional-neural-network, backpropagation

In the [Residual learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) paper by He et al., there are a number of plots of training/test error vs. backprop iteration. I've only ever seen "smooth" curves on these plots, while in this paper's application, there are sudden jumps in improvement. In this figure (Fig. 4a in the paper linked above), they are at around 15e4 and 30e4 iterations:

[image]

What happened here? My intuition would say that the backpropagation hit a plateau with a gradient of close to zero, and then *very suddenly* found a path steeply downward - but is that a realistic shape for a cost function?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into what learning rate scheduler they are using. This seems like an effect of reducing `lr` based on a Cosine or `ReduceOnPlateau` strategy. See a figure  from [Loshchilov et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03983v5)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for plateaus followed by steep drop. One possible reason are [saddle points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) on the error surface.

The error could be relatively constant in the saddle and then the optimizers "escapes" to a more optimal part of the error surface.